# In circleCI, more than 1 rspec test gives bundler: failed to load command: rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, circleci

How can I run more than 1 rspec test file with circle CI?

When I have one test in spec/features/main it runs fine.

However if I have another spec, they pass locally but in circleCI I get

```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec)
```

This happens even when I take the one "working in ci spec" and copy it to be a different filename but keep the contents the same.  When I do this it fails in circleCI with the above message

Everything I've tested shows that the issue is something about multiple files, not their actual content as above test showed.

The top of the file (that works if there is only file)is:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../support/page_object'
require_relative '../../support/sleep_lengths'
require_relative '../../support/sleepers'
```

Are my `require_relative`s messing up running a second file somehow ?

Circle uses the following to find the file:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mkdir /tmp/test-results
TEST_FILES="$(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)"

bundle exec rspec --format progress \
            --out /tmp/test-results/rspec.xml \
            --format progress \
            "${TEST_FILES}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two(2) things might be happening here:

1. "${TEST_FILES}" does not give correct substitution and therefore makes the whole `bundle exec rspec` command fail. You can try using this directly without the quotes in the `bundle exec rspec` command

   ```
   $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
   ```
2. Splitting by timings might be problematic if you have not run any successful test suites yet. Here is what I extracted from circle ci docs:

> The timings split type uses historical timing data to weight the
>   split. CircleCI automatically makes timing data from previous
>   successful runs available inside your container in a default location
>   so the CLI tool can discover them
>   ($CIRCLE_INTERNAL_TASK_DATA/circle-test-results).

So maybe you should just try splitting by filenames which is the default  or any other more explicit option like filesize rather than by timings. Something like this might help:

```
TEST_FILES="$(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split)"
```

Comment: For me, it was #1. Removing the quotes around `${TEST_FILES}` did the trick.